# Distibuted Computing in Julia Slower than Serial

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, julia, distributed-computing

I have a julia function that seems very amenable to optimization. Each iteration only manipulates the stuff in its particular index. Yet this function, when implemented with distributed as below, is *slower* than its serial equivalent. I have tried an equivalent implementation with Distributed instead of Shared arrays, and it is even slower. There must be something simple I am missing here, but I cannot figure it out.

```
function f(A1, A2, I1, I2, n1, n2, n3)
    B1 = convert(SharedArray, zeros(n1, n2))
    B2 = convert(SharedArray, zeros(n2, n3))
    @sync @distributed for d in 1:n2
        for i in 1:n3
            B1[d, i] = A1[I1[d], I2[d][i]] / (A1[I1[d], I2[d][i]] + A2[I1[d], I2[d][i]]))
            B2[:, d] .+= log.(A2[:, I2[d]);
        end
        B2[:, d] .-= logsumexp(B2[:, d])
    end
    B1 = convert(Array, B1)
    B2 = convert(Array, B2)
    
    B2 = exp.(B2)
    return B1, B2
end
```

Comment: I do know much about Julia but I expect the `@distributed` keyword to make some copies of the array used and this process can be slower than the actual copy. In fact, this is confirmed by [this](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/distributed-computing/) tutorial. Shared memory should theoretically help but it can also be more expensive regarding the access pattern. I expect this to be faster with a transposed B2 (and possibly A2 too) since the transposition will make accesses more contiguous. Multithreading may be better suited for your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of compute you're trying to distribute is likely much too small. Remember, all distributed computing has overhead of sending data back and forth between different processes, and that has a rather significant amount which needs to be overcome in order to actually speedup.

Comment: Hm, n2 here is on the order of 100 million so there is actually a fair bit of compute to distribute! Perhaps I am misunderstanding.

Comment: n2 may be large, but each work item (loop body) is not, which is the issue—with distributed compute you pay a large overhead per work item, so you'd better make it worth it.

Comment: Data transfer costs scale with the amount of data, so they scale like O(n). If you're doing an O(n) calculation, you might never be able to pay this cost. That's why distributed computing is normally associated with operations like lu-factorization and matrix multiplication, O(n^3) things where data reuse is extremely common and can payback this cost-per-data.